# Get selected value from Select Dropdown to modal before execute form POST action

Tags: php, html, forms, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to send a warning message for a "delete" click button in my web page through modal, containing the selected value from a dropdown menu.  But i'm can't figure it out how to make it work...

So far i have this.

```
<form action="elimina_cliente_seleccionado.php" method="POST">
  <select class="form-select" name="cliente">
    <option selected>Seleccione un cliente para borrar...</option>
    <?php
                // Iterating through the product array
                foreach($grupos as $item){
                    echo "<option value=$item>$item</option>";
                }
                ?>
  </select>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteModal">
    Eliminar cliente
  </button>
</form>
```

This is the modal.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Confirmación de la acción</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Está seguro que desea eliminar al cliente ........ ?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Borrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i take the selected value from the dropdown menu... uset it into the modal and display something like "Are you sure you want to delete the user USER1" and then execute a PHP FORM POST with the selected value?.

Any help much appreciated.
R.-

Comment: If possible, your Frontend should show warning directly without relaying on Backend, so that we only need a real `delete` route, not get-warning route.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the answer.  I forgot to mention that i'm not very skilled in html ... what do you mean by Frontend....??

Comment: Generally, anything in HTML and JS (if not Node.js) is called Frontend, and anything in PHP is Backend. I meant, use JS and/or jQuery (and don't add a route for each message).

Answer (score 1):

Looking for information and gathering pieces of code in several places i finally make the webpage work as i wanted.  Maybe somebody with more experience could tell me if this is ok.  Thanks!

I added an `id` tag for the `form`, `select` and `form button` as follows:

`<form id="formSelectUserDelete" action="hola.php" method="POST">`

`<select class="form-select" name="cliente" id="cliente">`

`<button id="botoncliente" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteModal"> Eliminar cliente</button>`

and manage all with javascript like this:

```
<script>
    $('#botoncliente').click(function(){
    //this is just getting the value that is selected
    var title = 'Esta seguro que quiere eliminar al cliente ' + $('#cliente').val() + '?';
    $('.modal-body').html(title);
    $('.modal').modal('show');
    });

    $(function() {
            $('#botonmodalborrar').on('click', function(e) {
            $('#formSelectUserDelete').submit();
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: forgot to mention that i also added an id for the modal button, like this : `id="botonmodalborrar"`